# Breaking constraints when the stackView is hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, constraints, uistackview

I'm using collectionView for chat box. There is a code that detects, if there is an attachment and changes the height of the collectionViewCell via

```
(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
```

In **cellForItemAt** I show or hide the stackView, depends is it file or not.

As I can see from print() this method executes first and then is `sizeForItemAt`. Why when I set `stackView.hidden = true` in `cellForItemAt` and is text message (then in `sizeForItemAt` I make height for the text message), breaks the constraints of the hidden stackView?

How constraints can be broken, when stackView is hidden? Basically there is no logic....

Answer (score 0):

Setting an element `.isHidden = true` does ***NOT*** remove any constraints related to that element.

For any UI object (not just a stack view), if you want its "space" removed when it is hidden you have a couple options.

1) Embed it and the other objects in a stack view (yes, you can embed a stack view in another stack view). Stack views automatically remove the space when an arranged subview is hidden.

2) Add an additional vertical space constraint to the object *above* the one you are hiding. Give the constraints different priorities, and change the priorities when you want to show or hide the related object. Here is an example that does just that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60817954/6257435